# React/Redux/Firebase: State updating, but component not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I'm trying to use Firebase's email verification API. I'm having react-router capture the incoming token, dispatching an action to verify the token is valid, then grabbing the currentUser's info to store to state. Using Chrome's Redux devTools, it looks like the state is updating just fine, but the component isn't re-rendering. As far as I can tell, I'm not mutating state and all of my references to the reducer object are correctly named.

Here's a bit of the code:

**Verify.jsx**

```
// The component the user lands on to verify email.
// Stateless - verification is handled by react-router dispatching action.

import React from 'react';
import * as Redux from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from 'actions';

import Alert from 'helpers/Alert';

export const Verify = React.createClass({

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <Alert
                    type="warning"
                    title="Verifying E-Mail"
                    message={(
                        <div>
                            <p>One moment please while we verify your e-mail...</p>
                            <i className="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw float-center"></i>
                        </div>
                    )}
                />
                <div className={`auth-content blur`}>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Redux.connect()(Verify);
```

**Actions.jsx**

```
export const verifyEmailWithCode = (oobCode) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.auth().applyActionCode(oobCode).then((success) => {
            // action code valid, add user to our database and send them to the main page
            if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
                const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                const uid = currentUser.uid;
                const email = currentUser.email;
                const user = {
                    uid,
                    email,
                    updatedAt: moment().format('LLLL'),
                    createdAt: moment().format('LLLL')
                };
                // add this user to our database
                databaseRef.child(`users/${uid}`).update(user);
                // store user to state (dispatches ADD_USER_DATA action - this should update component!)
                dispatch(storeUserDataToState(user));
                // route user to main logged in view
                dispatch(startLoginForAuthorizedUser(uid));
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("actions.jsx: Problem verifying email: ", error);
        });
    }
};

export const storeUserDataToState = (data) => {
    return{
        type: 'ADD_USER_DATA',
        data
    };
};
```

**Reducers.jsx**

```
export const userReducer = (state = initialUserState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_USER_DATA':
            // Add new user data to state
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.data
            };
        case 'RESET_USER_DATA':
            return initialUserState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

At this point, when I check devTools, it appears that the state updates fine. As you can see, state is not mutated - I'm returning a new object and populating the data from the previous two using the spread operator. However, my MainView component is not re-rendering with the updated state data:

**MainView.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Redux from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from 'actions';

export const MainView = React.createClass({

    render(){

        const { user } = this.props;

        // user object is still default even after state updated in devTools.

        return(
            <div>
                // None of this shows up
                { user.uid &&
                    <div>
                        <h3>Data:</h3>
                        <p><b>User ID: </b>{ user.uid }</p>
                        <p><b>Email: </b>{ user.email }</p>
                        <p><b>Updated At: </b>{ user.updatedAt }</p>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Redux.connect(state => {
    // State is still initialState here. 
    // state.user is the correct name of the reducer.
    return {
        user: state.user
    };
})(MainView);
```

**Routes.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import * as actions from 'actions';

// Components
import App from 'App';
import Landing from 'landing/Landing.jsx';
import Verify from 'landing/Verify.jsx';
import MainView from 'mainview/MainView.jsx';

import firebase from 'app/firebase';

const store = require('store').configure();

const requireLogin = (nextState, replace, next) => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(!currentUser){
        replace('/');
    }
    next();
};

const redirectIfLoggedIn = (nextState, replace, next) => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    currentUser ? replace('mainview') : console.log('no currentUser.');
    next();
};

const verifyUserEmail = (nextState, replace, next) => {
    const { mode, oobCode } = nextState.location.query;
    console.log("router: mode & oobCode from verifyUserEmail: ", mode, oobCode);
        if(mode == 'verifyEmail' && oobCode){
            store.dispatch(actions.verifyEmailWithCode(oobCode));
        } else {
            replace('/');
        }
    next();
}

export default (
    <Router history={ browserHistory }>
        <Route path="/" component={ App }>
            <IndexRoute component={ Landing } onEnter={ redirectIfLoggedIn } />
            <Route path="verify" component={ Verify } onEnter={ verifyUserEmail } />
            <Route path="mainview" component = { MainView } onEnter = { requireLogin } />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

**Store.jsx**

```
import * as redux from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { authReducer, imgUrlReducer, uiStateReducer, errorsReducer, userReducer } from 'reducers';

export var configure = (initialState = {}) => {
    var reducer = redux.combineReducers({
        form,
        auth: authReducer,
        imgUrl: imgUrlReducer,
        uiState: uiStateReducer,
        errors: errorsReducer,
        user: userReducer
    });

    // Add middleware here --
    var store = redux.createStore(reducer, initialState, redux.compose(
        redux.applyMiddleware(thunk),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    ));

    return store;
};
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong here? I've checked every question relating to this on SO and googled to death. I'm clueless.

Comment: At which point are you dispatching `verifyEmailWithCode`?  Can you also post the component responsible for this and the `storeUserDataToState` action creator?

Comment: @PatrickGrimard - I updated the original question with those two things. verifyEmailWithCode is dispatched by the router (onEnter) when the user first clicks the verification link (and Verify.jsx mounts). Note: Verify.jsx is stateless - it just displays an alert to the user letting them know we're validating their email.

Comment: Can you post your routes too?

Comment: @PatrickGrimard - Just did. Do you think dispatching verifyEmailWithCode at the router's onEnter is what's causing it? Maybe I should have the Verify component handle it?

Comment: It should work fine dispatching `verifyEmailWithCode` from the `onEnter` of the route, you've indicated the store updates.  I assume `const store = require('store').configure()` method uses `combineReducers` from Redux to assign your `userReducer` to `user`, in order for `state.user` to work in `MainView.jsx`?

Comment: @PatrickGrimard - That would be correct. I went ahead and added my Store.jsx code for clarification.

Comment: Although I've never used redux.compose, your setup looks ok.  Are you able to debug your MainView component and see what state looks like in Redux.connect after the state is updated?  I suspect state may not be what you're expecting, hence why the component isn't updating.

Comment: @PatrickGrimard - The state at Redux.connect in MainView is still the initialState, so while my tools are showing that the state updates, the component itself isn't receiving it for whatever reason. Update: I tried moving the verifycode dispatch from the router to MainView's componentDidMount method, and now it works how it's supposed to. Do you have any idea why that might be? Maybe there's some sort of miscommunication between react-router/react-redux and firebase?

Comment: Come to think of it, it looks like your routes are not wrapped with `<Provider>`.  So I'm not sure how your components are able to access the store, unless you're passing the store explicitly as a prop.  If you wrap your routes with `<Provider>`, then store becomes implicitly available as a prop to each component.  That being said, I'm unsure if that's the reason your dispatch wasn't working from the route `onEnter`.  I've used this approach before without any issues, but I admit I prefer doing that kind of thing in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/pgrimard/spring-boot-webpack/blob/2.1.0/src/main/resources/app/scripts/index.js#L12 for an example of using `<Provider>`.

Comment: @PatrickGrimard - I do have my <Provider> at the highest level app component (code not posted above). Thank you for your help, though - I'll definitely use componentDidMount from here on out for these types of things.

Comment: The componentDidMount approach is probably more future proof in my opinion.  If the react-router API changes and they drop support for onEnter, you'd be stuck refactoring your code in order to upgrade to the later version of react-router.  Or I'm just paranoid ;)